# Repeater Control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater control that displays a playlist for my users, this control can sometimes hold say 1000 or more songs.  This is a great feature, I was previously using jQuery to do client side sorting, but that has limitations.  So I implemented server side sorting which works great, the only issue i am seeing is that when playlist are this long it takes a second or 2 before the postback and sorting is actually started.

I have watched the actions in firebug and done some research and understand that the databound values are not preserved, which makes sence.  My question is, When watching in Firebug, it looks like the repeater control removes all the items in the collection before it starts the postback?  is this true have others experienced this?

Comment: you better have Paging in place..

Answer (score 1):

The repeater control ceases to exist entirely between postbacks. The repeater control is called into existance when you make a page request. It is populated, etc. then rendered to the browser. Once done, ASP.NET will delete all the objects on the page (or rather the garbage collector will get them when required. Either way, you can't get them any more).

When the postback happens it has to re-create the entire repeater all over again. There are some mechanisms, such as viewstate, that try to make this as seamless as possible (i.e. recreating controls just as you left them in the previous request) but they sometimes don't work the way you might expect.

Comment: That is what I am seeing the GC removing the items, i am just surpised by the delay but it is only there when there are a 1000 or more rows/items.  Thanks

Comment: The delays is most likely caused by having to rebuild the content of your repeater each time. You may like to have a look at the various methods of caching to see if any are suitable for your situation it might help rebuild the control faster if you are getting the data from an external source each time.